# Exposing temporal data - is this RESTful?

Tags: rest

**Background/Context:**

I have a very simple use case that I am attempting to use as an opportunity to build support within my company for hypermedia-rich API development.  What I'm trying to determine - with the help of the wonderful stackoverflow community :) - is whether my proposed implementation ticks all the boxes to call itself "RESTful".

As promised, the use case is quite simple - we have a data table where we track some sort of location classification code on a per zipcode basis.  The only thing remotely interesting about this table is that we have - via the from/thru dates - the concept of effectivity:

*Table State 1*

```
 ID | ZIP  | CODE | FROM      | THRU
====|======|======|===========|===========
548 |90210 |R     |2013-01-01 |null
```

We get updated data every fall that takes effect Jan 1st of the following year.  For example, if the above zipcode was being updated to a new "CODE" value, we'd make the following table changes:

*Table State 2*

```
 ID | ZIP  | CODE | FROM      | THRU
====|======|======|===========|===========
548 |90210 |R     |2013-01-01 |2014-12-31
777 |90210 |U     |2015-01-01 |null
```

Of course, one could expose this interaction as a CRUD service in their sleep, call it "RESTful", and be done with it in short order.  PUT to update the old record's "THRU" date; POST to insert a record reflecting the new data.

Easy enough, but as I mentioned, I'm trying to use this opportunity to do a hypermedia case study - here is my proposed design (conveyed via some sample requests).  Here is how I would propose getting from *Table State 1* to *Table State 2*:

**Request 1:**

```
GET /zips/90210
```

**Response 1:**

```
200 OK

{"zipCode":90210,"pickupLocationCode":"R","fromDate":"2013-01-01","thruDate":null,
 "_links":{"self":{"href":"/zips/90210"},
           "latest":{"href":"/zips/90210"}}}
```

**Request 2:**

```
PUT /zips/90210

{"zipCode":90210,"pickupLocationCode":"U","fromDate":"2015-01-01","thruDate":null}
```

**Response 2:**

```
204 No Content
```

**Request 3:**

```
GET /zips/90210
```

**Response 3:**

```
200 OK

{"zipCode":90210,"pickupLocationCode":"U","fromDate":"2015-01-01","thruDate":null,
 "_links":{"self":{"href":"/zips/90210"},
           "previous":{"href":"/zips/90210/0"},
           "latest":{"href":"/zips/90210"}}}
```

**Request 4:**

```
GET /zips/90210/0
```

**Response 4:**

```
200 OK

{"zipCode":90210,"pickupLocationCode":"R","fromDate":"2013-01-01","thruDate":"2014-12-31",
 "_links":{"self":{"href":"/zips/90210/0"},
           "next":{"href":"/zips/90210"},
           "latest":{"href":"/zips/90210"}}}
```

Note that the PUT in Request 2 automagically "expired" the old row (i.e. set the thru date) and then inserted a new row.

I'm attempting to allow clients to (1) locate a given zipcode via a URL using a well-known business key (e.g. "90210") and then (2) via hypermedia ("next", "previous", "latest" link rels), allow the client to navigate through the zipcode's various states at different points in time.  Am I headed down the right path here or am I on a fool's errand?

Using this design, if you ever wanted to "delete" a zipcode (I'm guessing this rarely - if ever? - happens, but again, trying to use this as more of an academic exercise than anything), you could do some interesting stuff:

**Delete Request:**

```
DELETE /zips/90210
```

**Delete Response:**

```
204 No Content
```

A subsequent GET to /zips/90210 would give you:

```
303 See Other
Location: /zips/90210/0
```

This would allow you to make a valuable distinction between (1) a zipcode for which we no longer have any "active" data for and (2) a zipcode that never existed to begin with - for instance:

```
GET /zips/99999
```

Which would give you a good old 404:

```
404 Not Found
```

Inserting a new zipcode (a use case that probably *does* happen semi-frequently) would simply be a matter of making an exploratory GET to confirm that zip doesn't currently exist (i.e. either a 303 See Other or 404 Not Found response) and then making a POST to the base "/zips" URL.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where the URI for request 2 comes from? That looks like out-of-band information? What's the point in putting to `/0` instead of to the original URI and allowing the version tracking to take place under the hood?

Comment: Whoops - that was a typo (which I've now fixed, thanks).  My intent there was indeed a PUT to the original URI, just like you said.

Comment: OK. You don't mention custom media-types anywhere. What is the media-type for a zip code and a collection of zip codes?

Comment: That is a good question - I'm envisioning some sort of application-specific media type (e.g. "application/vnd.myorg.zipcode+json"), but honestly have not thought that far ahead yet.